# UILocalNotification shows 400 badges

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uilocalnotification

I am scheduling a UILocalNotification for an interval. Basically I wanted a notification to be triggered every x days on this app. So the way I did it is to schedule a bunch of notifications at once. So say it's every 2 days, then I do a calculation of the dates every 2 days from now for a year. I am not sure if this is the right and most efficient solution to it, but from researching online, this is what I get I need to do.

The issue is that when the notification fires and I open the app, the badges count goes up to 500, which I think is the number of all future notifications I've scheduled. How is this even possible> Shouldn't the badge only show the number of notifications before the timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The badge number does not show a number of notifications, but the badge value that you set as notification payload.

Comment: So how do I set this notification payload?

Comment: Those are properties on UILoalNotification.